# why terms for longfield is not correct?

Tags: lucene

A simple test with Lucene 4.9.
use RamDirectory index two document, width 3 fileds [longdata, stringdata, textdata].

documents

[2000000L, "hello g", "hello g"]
[4000000L, "world","world"]

here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Directory directory = null;
    IndexWriter iwriter = null;
    Analyzer analyzer = new SmartChineseAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);
    directory = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9, analyzer);
    iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new LongField("longdata", 2000000L, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new LongField("longdata", 4000000L, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("stringdata", "hello g", Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("stringdata", "world", Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("textdata", "hello g", Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("textdata", "world", Field.Store.YES));
    iwriter.addDocument(doc);
    iwriter.close();

    DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(ireader);
    System.out.println("longdata========");
    Terms terms = fields.terms("longdata");
    TermsEnum iterator = terms.iterator(null);
    BytesRef byteRef = null;
    while ((byteRef = iterator.next()) != null) {
        System.out.println(NumericUtils.prefixCodedToLong(byteRef));
    }
    System.out.println("stringdata========");
    Terms strterms = fields.terms("stringdata");
    TermsEnum striterator = strterms.iterator(null);
    BytesRef strbyteRef = null;
    while ((strbyteRef = striterator.next()) != null) {
        System.out.println(strbyteRef.utf8ToString());
    }
    System.out.println("textdata========");
    Terms textterms = fields.terms("textdata");
    TermsEnum textiterator = textterms.iterator(null);
    BytesRef textbyteRef = null;
    while ((textbyteRef = textiterator.next()) != null) {
        System.out.println(textbyteRef.utf8ToString());
    }

    ireader.close();
    directory.close();
}
```

it's OUTPUT

```
longdata========
2000000
4000000
1966080
3997696
0
0
stringdata========
hello g
world
textdata========
g
hello
world
```

My question is why there are so many long term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene indexes numeric fields in brackets of lower and lower precision increments (controlled by the precision step), allowing it more more effectively (and quickly) home in on correct matches.

If you take a look at the binary representation of these numbers, it becomes a bit more evident what is going on:

```
4000000 = 0b1111010000100100000000
3997696 = 0b1111010000000000000000

2000000 = 0b111101000010010000000
1966080 = 0b111100000000000000000
```